# Not all mouse buttons working as expected on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

Recently I noticed that not all buttons on my mouse are working as expected. Some buttons are just not recognized and one other just outputs left click. I verified this with xev and pynput.
I searched for how to remap keys, but I din not find anything on remapping keys that dont even register.

My mouse Is the Logitech G G502 Hero and im using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: The additional buttons are programmable and depend on proprietary software not available for Linux/Ubuntu. There's a community effort (non-official) called Solaar but it doesn't (yet) support yours: https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/devices.html

Comment: Is that the only option? For clarification: I dont need a software to handle macros for me. The only thing that I need is thze ability to intercept keys in a python script or something similar.